# Imlementing twiiter4j using username and password

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to use twitter4j to login user's userid and password.
I found a class BasicAuthorization which allows to login using userid and pasword.
But what now? After login how to access tweets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter stopped supporting Basic Authentication in the Twitter API for a long time, so you must use OAuth.

For more information, you can see Twitter4J 2.2.5 changelog.

> · retirement of Basic authentication (TFJ-560)

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, Now i am moving to OAuth Authentication. And can you please tell me a step by step procedure to use OAuth authentication and i want my user to search tweets by keywords.